# Duplicate attribute regex simplification

Tags: java, regex, simplify

I am looking for duplicate attributes within the code base, I threw an expression together that works, but I am wondering if it can be made any simpler or more logical.

**Sample input**

```
test.append("<td class='no-order' style='text-align:center;' class=\"data text\">");
```

**My attempt**

```
<([^>]*)(class=('|\\")[^('|\\")]+('|\\"))([^>]*)(class=('|\\")[^('|\\")]+('|\\"))([^>]*)>
```

My thinking was looking for a start tag `<` then anything that is not an end tag `[^>]*` followed by a class attribute with either `'` or `\"` and then repeating the whole thing.

As you can see, even though it works, it looks quite long and complicated, is their a simpler way?

**Edit:**

super bonus brownie points for whoever writes it in the form of a replace all, so it combines the attribute values after running

Comment: you could use capturing groups.. check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: the thing is a backreference matches _exactly_ the specified match, what if the attributes have different content? `class="hello", class="wow"`

Comment: are you really concerned about "hello" and "wow"?. Both are just names.. You just need class="...." right?

Comment: consider using [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) instead of regex. There are [many reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) you should no use regex to parse html.

Comment: @JohnMercier, completely missing the point of the question... I have already accepted an answer. this was for a search and replace, not for parsing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
<.+(class)=("|').+?\2.+?\1.+>
```

Escape the regex before you use it.

And if it `matches` the string, then it **contains** duplicates. Else, it doesn't.

Explanation:

`<.+(class)=("|')` matches the `<` plus any characters till it reaches `class=` single or double quotes.

The rest of the regex matches the value **only** if the string contains `class` again somewhere along the line using backreference.

Comment: Very smart, i did not think about _only_ matching for another class attribute, ugh so simple.. accepting

Comment: Do you *really* have to create a capture group? ;-)

Comment: @epoch, be sure to escape the regex. And I saw the edit. You can't do it with `replaceAll` so easily. You need to do some replace, check if it is equal to original and all sort of things. So, just use `matches` which does it for you ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki What will `<.+class=("|').+?\2.+?class.+>` do?

Comment: @thefourtheye, it will do the same ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye mine is [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) `:)`

Comment: Its not working if there are multiple tags in single line like this: 
`<td height="26" width="99%" align="left" valign="top" nowrap><img src="/images/load.gif" width="100%" height="26" border="0"/></td>` Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `class=("|')` to check for the multiple class attributes.

Sample code:

```
    String str = "test.append(\"<td class='no-order' style='text-align:center;' class=\"data text\">\");";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("class=(\"|')");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    int index = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        index++;
    }

    if (index > 1) {
        System.out.println("multiple class attribute found");
    }
```

output:

```
multiple class attribute found
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on what Amit Joki suggested, if you want to make sure it's in the same element you could use:

`<.+(class)=("|').+?\2[^>]+?\1.+>`

The addition of `[^>]` will make sure your second class attribute will reside in the same element as it will match anything except the closing of the tag.